# Why is if (empty($_SESSION['gebruikersnaam']['wachtwoord'])) not working?

Tags: php, session

first off all my English is not very good. Sorry I do my best. I am developing a CMS system. I need an inlog system for it. If you are not logged in you can't view some of the pages. I created a php session of it but it doesn't work on the other pages... I will include some off the code I wrote.

1. On the page I check the username and password, I created the session like this. And worked with session to check username and password, so it works on that page.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSSION['gebruikersnaam'] = $_POST['gebruikersnaam'];
$_SESSSION['wachtwoord'] = $_POST['wachtwoord'];

if(($_SESSSION['gebruikersnaam'] == 'admin')
    && ($_SESSSION['wachtwoord'] == 'admin123')) {
    include("adminpanel.php");
} else {
    echo "Uw gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord is foutief.";
}
?>
```

2. On my other pages I added this to check if the user is logged in. I seem to never get that I am logged in and I can't echo the session out. Here is the code!

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['gebruikersnaam']['wachtwoord'])) { 
    echo "not ingelogd";
}
```

If the conditional statement with the session works, I can redirect the user to the log in page if he is not logged in.

Thanks in advance you would help me a lot!

Comment: I see `_SESSSION`, check that typo.

Comment: `$_SESSSION['gebruikersnaam']` is one value, `$_SESSSION['wachtwoord']` is another.

Comment: did you start the session on that page?

Comment: @RST It's the 3th line of his code..

Comment: @Xorifelse I meant on his other pages. He says he can't echo the value (hopefully he knows it is an array so he needs print_r() or something), so I wondered if he used start_session() on those pages

Comment: @RST The 4th and 5th line he sets the values. 2 possible ways it can fail, either `$_POST` is not set or the session file is `flock()`'ed

Comment: @Xorifelse not sure why we are having this conversation but when you setup everything correctly in one file and have no access to the values in ANOTHER file then most likely you forgot to start the session in that OTHER file. And if not, it doesn't hurt to check. And I just noticed Johnish is saying the same thing in his answer, why aren't you bothering him?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of a slip of the tongue, its `$_SESSION` not `$_SESSSION` and also:

```
$_SESSION['gebruikersnaam']['wachtwoord'];
```

Is actually referring to 1 value, not two:

```
$data = array('gebruikersnaam' => array('wachtwoord' => 'mijnwachtwoord'));
echo $data['gebruikersnaam']['wachtwoord'];
```

Instead do:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['gebruikersnaam']) || !empty($_SESSION['wachtwoord'])){ 
  echo "not ingelogd";
}
```

However, you should only store a username and id in a session. Storing the password is a potential security breach and is not necessary.

You could also use something like this to scan for required values:

```
function required_session_fields(array $keys){
  foreach($keys as $k){
    if(!array_key_exists($k, $_SESSION) && empty($_SESSION[$k])){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

if(required_session_fields(['gebruikersnaam', 'wachtwoord'])){
  echo 'gelukt';
}
```

If you started the session and included a file, you can still access the `$_SESSION` variable. On every *new* server request, make sure the session is started.

Comment: Welcome to [so], if an answer is useful, upvote. If it solved your question mark it. Next time include small details as @RST mentioned, we don't know what's happening in your other pages so create a [mcve] on those too.

Answer (score 0):

2. On the other pages you must have

   session_start();

before

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['gebruikersnaam']['wachtwoord'])) { 
  echo "not ingelogd";
}
```

However this variable $_SESSION['gebruikersnaam']['wachtwoord'] is never created. Currently you have created $_SESSION['gebruikersnaam'] and $_SESSION['wachtwoord']

Perhaps you meant to have something like

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['gebruikersnaam']) && !empty($_SESSION['wachtwoord'])) { 
      echo "not ingelogd";
    }
```